# Hyperlink doesn't work in textview

Tags: android, hyperlink

In a certain activity, I made an hyperlink in the middle of a textview. In a new activity, i wanted to do the same thing. However, with the exact same code, just another website, it doesn't work. 
Does anyone have a solution for this? This is my strings.xml code, the activity "afspraak" is the one where i'm trying to get 2 hyperlinks. In activity "contact" I have them already:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Rodekruis</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_nieuws">NieuwsActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_afspraak"><b>Afspraak</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Maken en wijzigen</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Zelf uw afspraak maken of wijzigen? Dat kan, mits us al als patiënt geregistreerd staat bij het RKZ. Is dit nog niet het geval? Dan wordt de afspraak telefonish gepland. Meer info&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Bekijk ook</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\u2022   Wat neem ik mee naar een eerste afspraak?<a href='https://www.rkz.nl/eerste_polikliniekbezoek'> </a>&lt;br /&gt;\u2022    Wat zijn de wachttijden? <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/wachttijden'> </a></string>
    <string name="title_activity_bezoek"><b>Bezoektijden</b>\n\nVrijwel iedere patiënt vindt het prettig bezoek te ontvangen. Onze ervaring is
    dat een goed contact met vrienden en familie een bijdrage kan leveren aan 
    een spoedig herstel.\n\nVoor de meeste afdelingen gelden de volgende bezoektijden:\nvan 15.15 tot 16.15 uur;\nvan 19.00 tot 20.00 uur.\n\nLet op: tijdens feestdagen gelden in het RKZ andere bezoektijden dan normaal.
    Bekijk de website voor uitgebreide bezoektijden.
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_contact">&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Contact</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Telefoon en internet Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5555 (algemeen nummer, ook Poli IJmuiden)&lt;br /&gt;www.rkz.nl<a href='https://www.rkz.nl'> </a>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Huisartsenpost Midden-Kennemerland (begane grond RKZ)&lt;br /&gt;Voor huisartsenzorg buiten kantooruren&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5265&lt;br /&gt;
    (A.u.b. bellen voordat u langskomt)&lt;br /&gt; Spoedeisende Hulp RKZ en Huisartsenpost: meer informatie&lt;br /&gt;Bij levensbedreigende klachten belt u altijd 112&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Bezoek- en postadres Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;Vondellaan 13&lt;br /&gt;1942 LE Beverwijk&lt;br /&gt;Route(link)&lt;br /&gt;Postbus 1074&lt;br /&gt;1940 EB Beverwijk
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_mening">MeningActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_route">\n\n\n\n<b>Route</b>\n\nRode Kruis Ziekenhuis, hoofdgebouw\nVondellaan 13\n1942 LE Beverwijk\n\nDe Velsertunnel is van medio mei tot eind 2016 gesloten.\nVoor verkeer vanuit zuidelijke richting is het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis in Beverwijk hierdoor moeilijker bereikbaar. Bekijk: \n\n\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie korte routes naar/van het RKZ\n\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie langere routers naar/van het RKZ\n\u2022    plan uw route naar/van het RKZ met      actuele verkeersinformatie\n\nRKZ Poli IJmuiden (tijdelijk i.v.m. sluiting Velsertunnel)\nGezondheidscentrum Het Plein\nPlein 1945, nr.1\nIJmuiden\n\u2022    Plan uw route(Google maps)\n\u2022    Meer informatie over de Poli IJmuiden</string>
    <string name="title_activity_specialisten">SpecialistenActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_bwc">  &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;<b>Brandwondencentrum</b>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Het RKZ Brandwondencentrum, beter bekend als: Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk, levert al meer dan veertig jaar topklinische zorg op het gebied van huid-, brandwonden- en littekenbehandelingen en wordt zowel in het binnen- als buitenland hoog gewaardeerd.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Wie werken er in het Brandwondencentrum? Wat maakt het centrum zo bijzonder? Wat is een brandwond precies, wanneer is behandeling in het Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk nodig? Welke behandelingen vinden er plaats? Hoe vindt een opname plaats en wat zijn de bezoekregels? En welke afdelingen en poliklinieken behoren tot het brandwondencentrum?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van Brandwondencentrum worden deze vragen uitegebreid beantwoord.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk heeft speciaal voor kinderen en tieners een <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> </a>
    </string>
    <string name="title_activity_agenda">AgendaActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_info">InfoActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_vriend">\n\n\n\n<b>Word vriend van het RKZ</b>\n\nEen verblijf in het ziekenhuis is meestal niet erg plezierig. De Stichting Vrienden van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis spant zich in om het verblijf van patiënten, bezoekers en medewerkers van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis en het bijbehorende Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk te veraangenamen. Door geld in te zamelen voor voorzieningen die niet uit het basisbudget van het ziekenhuis kunnen worden betaald. Denk aan een opknapbeurt voor de speelkamer voor jonge patiënten of een verwenbehandeling bij een chemokuur.\n\nOok u kunt helpen. Door Vriend te worden van het RKZ of door ons eenmalig te steunen. Lees verder op de website.\n\nMet vrienden om je heen voel je je beter. Geef om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis. 
    </string>
    <string name="title_activity_folders">FoldersActivity</string>

</resources>
```

This is my Main Activity code:

```
    package com.example.rodekruis;

    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.text.Html;
    import android.text.Spanned;
    import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView

;

public class AfspraakActivity extends Activity {

     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_afspraak);

        TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setClickable(true);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        String text = getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_afspraak);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    }





}
```

edit: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z48Xt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in xml:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(
            "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
            "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
            "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.. I already had the autolink=web line, I added the linksClickable, still doesn't work. It doesn't even show as a link, just normal text.

Comment: Is this suppose to be in XML or my main activity?

Comment: @Koendebaas, your main activity

Comment: Removes all my text and only shows :" created in the Java source doe using HTML.

Comment: @Koendebaas, are you able to click on textview ?

Comment: No, it just shows it, nothing is clickable. I can add screenshots if you want

Comment: @Koendebaas, yes please

Comment: If you want me to link something else, or want me to show something else, feel free to ask. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't got any more answers, please say so as well. So that I can just give up this hyperlink part :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: same as below, removes all my text except one line

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% working for me .Try this . Although this is not the exact solution but still it can do job for you .

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "Enter your link here";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Open via"));
```

Comment: This does something really weird. When i open the activity it sends me to a textmessage directly. When i cancel that The textview is there, but no links

Comment: In your xml code , under <TextView section , use
     android:onClick="link"  and the above code should be put in method named link()

Comment: use what? :o hoping you'd finish that sentence